# How to retrieve / read SQL Image Data which is stored in the database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

From one application, we are storing all images in SQL database in the Image datatype. From another application, i need to retrieve the images and display it on User Interface.

I am able to store the images. I am not able to read the images.

How to retrieve / read SQL Image Data which is stored in the database ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)
- [FILESTREAM MVC: Download and Upload images from SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2011/02/06/filestream-mvc-download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server/)

For a winforms or a WPF applicaiton things are simpler, just assign the BLOB stream to the image [`StreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) property.

Comment: Thank you !! But i havent expected on MVC ..!! I tried to do is more simple from SQL Query !! But thank you !!